# change the blog in the url if you go from a specific page wordpress

Tags: php, posts, permalinks, urls

I have a products page on my site, and the products themselves are actually posts.
And also, I have a blog with posts. When I am on the products page, I have a link like:

```
site.com/products
```

And go to the product page (post), I get a link:

```
site.com/blog/product1
```

This is the normal default behavior since the product is a post.

But how do I change blog to products if I go to product (post) from product page? like this:

```
site.com/products/product1
```

The `admin->settings->permalink` variant is not for my case, as the site also has blog posts!

Thank you!

Comment: doing this will cause duplicate content SEO penalties for having the same content in multiple places. You'll also need to remove the canonical URL redirect that tries to protect you from this, otherwise even if you get links to the post showing with /blog in some places and /products in others, WP would redirect you to the "canonical" official URL which is standard and expected behaviour. It also means your sitemaps won't make sense since there'll be URLs that don't appear there, etc. Ideally you should have 1 URL for a post and only 1 URL to avoid these issues